# PayPal Successful Payment

Tags: paypal

I have created a form that directs the visitor to PayPal to create a subscription. I have specified two return URLs, one for success and one for failure.

Can I guarantee that if the returned user arrives at the success URL, I can update my database to indicate that user has created a valid subscription?

Thanks

Comment: that would be a question for the people that wrote the API you are accessing.  This is not their support site.

Comment: No you can't. There is no security around it, for a start, and it also doesn't imply that the money has been transferred yet. From the business point of view, you should wait until you receive the money. You can use IPN for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use PDT or IPN (recommended) :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/